# Add or remove or reload a specific VirtualHost without restarting Apache (and having other VirtualHosts' requests interrupted)

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

Context: Let's say I have this `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file (Debian 9, Apache 2.4):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
</VirtualHost>
```

and that some clients are currently browsing this website, and even some of them are busy downloading a 1 GB file on this website (let's say they're downloading `www.example.com/bigfile.zip`).

**Now I want to add a new `VirtualHost`** and I edit the `000-default.conf` file to (and save it):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I do

```
service apache2 restart
```

it will successfully enable the new website `example2.com`, but also stop all on-going requests from clients for example.com, and it will break for example the downloads in progress.

**Question: is there a way to add a new `VirtualHost` and not interrupt on-going requests (long downloads, etc.) for other `VirtualHost`s?**

Note:

- I have already read [How to reload apache configuration for a site without restarting apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270108/how-to-reload-apache-configuration-for-a-site-without-restarting-apache) but the question and answer are not precise about what is the consequences "of not restarting" Apache. The same about [Can I “reload” Apache2 configuration file without issues?](https://superuser.com/q/192686/221041), I'm not sure about what would happen in the case of an ongoing 20-minutes download from a client. Would it wait or not? This question here focuses specifically on adding a new VirtualHost while not breaking the others' requests.
- I have also ready many similar questions, but this one addresses a precise specific requirement: install a new `VirtualHost` while not interrupting ongoing requests such as long downloads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restart == stop, then start.

Instead use `apachectl graceful`.  Graceful lets existing connections complete, then restarts each sub-process one by one, as they are freed.  New connections will get the new configuration.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#graceful

Comment: What is the difference between `apachectl -k graceful` and `apachectl graceful` @Nic3500? I see both in the doc, but nowhere the `-k` is explained.

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/777622/what-is-the-apache2ctl-k-flag.  `-k` is passed to httpd, no `-k` is handled by `apachectl`.